# Convert st_distance result to kilometers or meters

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-5.6

I need get closest subdistrict to metro station. I use  function `St_distance` from this topic:
[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46913359/find-closest-subdistrict-to-point-on-map/46913652)
. How can I convert `st_distance` result to kilometers or meters? I have **mysql 5.6**, so I can't use `st_distance_sphere` or another new functions.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can multiply the resulting value by 111195 - this value is (Earth mean radius)*PI/180 - that is 'mean length of one great circle degree in meters on Earth's surface'. Warning: the result will not be too correct.

Or use plain old [haversine formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Haversine_formula).

Comment: I don't need very exact result, so I think this method is good for me

Answer (score 0):

First you have to figured out what unit your geography data is configured.

If you can, configure your SRID to 4326, for example. That will return the results in meters. If you can't change it, you have to figured out what unit you're using and simply apply the conversion to whatever unit you want.

Comment: 4326 SRID is not using meters. It is a degree based reference system (https://epsg.io/4326). For getting real units (meters, feet) you have to pick something applicable for the region you are working on. For USA it is 2877 (however I have doubts MYSQL understands it, when PostGRES sure does)